# linux shell script if else statement

Tags: shell

```
[root@linux ~]# cat show-spans | grep Down
PRI span 1/0: In Alarm, Down, Active
PRI span 3/0: In Alarm, Down, Active
PRI span 4/0: In Alarm, Down, Active
```

### im specifying grep only span 1 & span 2 below commands to find down

```
[root@samba ~]# cat show-spans | grep -e 1 -e 2 | grep Down
PRI span 1/0: In Alarm, Down, Active
```

I want to write if else state ment

If found word "Down" while use grep command  email alert or else don't shoot email

I'm using ssmtp for email alerts like below

```
cat show-spans | grep -e 1 -e 2 | grep Down| mail -s "Test email alert" indiaxxx@gmail.com
```

i want to make it as script. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I can quickly see at least 3 options.

1. The obvious with temporary file:

   ```
   F=$(mktemp)
   if cat show-spans | grep Down >"$F"; then
       mail -s "Test email alert" indiaxxx@gmail.com <"$F"
   fi
   rm -f "$F"
   ```

   The disadvantage is that it creates a temporary file. Which is completely unnecessary.
2. If the text is not long (I presume it won't be), using variable instead of file:

   ```
   TEXT=$(cat show-spans | grep Down)
   if [ -n "$TEXT" ]; then
       printf "%s\n" "$TEXT" | mail -s "Test email alert" indiaxxx@gmail.com
   fi
   ```

   (alternatively the if can test `[ 0 = $? ]`; grep always prints something if it finds and nothing if it does not, so testing non-empty output or grep exit status is equivalent).

   Note, that command substitution strips *trailing* white-space, but otherwise it preserves all characters including newlines, so this *will* work with multiple lines.

   The `printf` command is more reliable than `echo`, because `echo` interprets some escape sequences and there are mutually incompatible implementations that do that differently. `printf` only interprets escapes in the first argument.
3. For big inputs still without temporary file:

   ```
   cat show-spans | grep Down | {
       if read FIRST; then
           {
                printf "%s\n" "$FIRST"
                cat
           } | mail -s "Test email alert" indiaxxx@gmail.com
      fi
   }
   ```

   The `read` will try to read first line of grep output and if it succeeds, it is reprinted and the rest copied via cat directly to `mail`. The `read` should probably be `read -r` to avoid interpreting escape sequences *if* your shell supports it.

Comment: Thank you very much Jan Hudec.

Actually pri show spans command out put only i have printed output in show-spans file..

So as you said we don't want to create unnecessary file like show-spans valid point.

Which step shall i go for it

Option 3 ? or you u have changes pls guide me

Comment: I think option 2 is shortest and most to the point. Use the option 3 if there is a risk that the output will be huge (hundreds of kilobytes or more).

Comment: [root@samba ~]# ./alert.sh
Send options without primary recipient specified.
Usage: mail -eiIUdEFntBDNHRV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS -c USERS -S OPTION users
[root@samba ~]# vi alert.sh
[root@samba ~]# cat alert.sh
TEXT=$(cat show-spans | grep Down)
if [ -n "$TEXT" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "$TEXT" | mail -s "Test email alert"indiaxxx@gmail.com
fi

Comment: @san: I think you are missing space in the arguments to `mail`.

Comment: TEXT=$(cat show-spans | grep Down)
if [ -n "$TEXT" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "$TEXT" | mail -s "Test email alert"indiaxxx@gmail.com                      Check is this correct ? pl help

Comment: @san: Still missing space.